# Udev rules not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, usb, udev

I have a Udev rule on a scanner device, which is suppose to work on USB removal, but it is not working.

Rules on USB add is working.

```
# Scanner Add
KERNEL=="tty[A-Z]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ACTION=="123", ATTRS{idVendor}=="123", ATTRS{idProduct}=="456", RUN+="runDummy.sh"

# Scanner Remove
KERNEL=="tty[A-Z]*", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{PRODUCT}=="***", RUN+="runDummy.sh"
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing `runDummy.sh` and the actual property tree for your scanner device (use `udevadm`), but note that the "work" udev rule scripts can do is severely limited (read `man 7 udev` section `RUN` carefully). Debugging udev rules is no fun, the best results I had were with restarting `udevd` with debugging enabled.

Comment: runDummy.sh is just doing echo "Hello", it is working fine for USB add.

Comment: Please *edit* your question with additional information; comments may not stick around. Any particular reason the "remove" rule is not the equivalent of the "add" rule (different `SUBSYSTEM`; different `ACTION` (though that may have been ean edit), no matching `ATTRS`, instead several `ENV`, etc.)?